# Wrong template being rendered for modal in AngularJS Boostrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Newbie to AngularJS and have a Chat App project that calls for use of AngularFire/uiBootstrap. I need to generate a modal to create a new chat room. Not sure where my bug is, but my `modal.open()` function simply duplicates the view (`home.html` template) instead of rendering the modal.

My `home.html` view is inserted into `index.html` via ui-router's `ui-view`

I used an `app.js` file with a state provider and set `home.html`'s controller there

I'll include my templates and controllerS.

HOME.HTML:

```
<h1>Bloc Chat</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="chat in home.chatRooms">{{ chat.$value }}</li>
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="home.open()">New 
room</button>
```

MODAL.HTML FILE:

```
<div class="my-modal ng-scope" id="my-modal">
<!-- <div class="my-modal" id="my-modal" controller="ModalInstanceCtrl"> -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Create a new room</h3>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
      <form>
        Enter a room name<br>
        <input type="text" name="new-room-name">
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="modal.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="modal.save()">Create Room</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HOMECTRL.JS

```
(function() {
  function HomeCtrl(Room, $scope, $uibModal, $log, $document) {
    var home = this;

    this.chatRooms = Room.all;
    //TO TEST ADD METHOD FROM ROOM.JS
    // this.addRoom = Room.add();

    this.open = function () {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'modal',
        bindToContoller: true,
        size: 'sm'
      });
    }

  };

  angular
    .module('blocChat')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['Room', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', '$document', HomeCtrl]);
})();
```

MODALCTRL.JS

```
(function() {
  function ModalInstanceCtrl(Room, home, $scope, $uibModalInstance, $log, $document) {

  this.save = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  this.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };

  }

  angular
    .module('blocChat')
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['Room', '$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$log', '$document', ModalInstanceCtrl]);
})();
```

Comment: what happens if you open that template url in browser address bar?

Comment: An error: "Your file was not found. It may have been moved or deleted"

Comment: Seems like you have a path problem then

Comment: You're right, I did. I had to change path to `../templates/modal.html` Thanks so  much for your help!